# Can we downcast to UItableview to UItableviewcell?

Tags: swift

Can we  downcast to `UITableview` to `UITableviewCell`?

I am so confused as per to my knowledge, down casting is the process between super class and subclass  but in below coding

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Categorycell")as? CategoryCell{
        let category=DataService.instance.getCategories()[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateViews(categories: category)
        return cell

    }else{
        return CategoryCell()
     }
   }
```

`UITableview` has been downcast to `UItableviewCell`
but I jump those types definition both are not related (via hierarchy)

```
 class CategoryCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImage:UIImageView!
     @IBOutlet weak var categoryTitle:UILabel!

    func updateViews(categories:Category) {
        categoryImage.image=UIImage(named: categories.imageName)
        categoryTitle.text=categories.title
    }

 }
```

Comment: "`Can we downcast to UItableview to UItableviewcell?`", No. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Since you are not downcasting in your code example they way you say I fail to see the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not downcasting from `UITableView` to `UITableViewCell`. In the function `cellForRowAt`, you are only dequeuing reusable cells and those cells are the ones you are downcasting to your custom table view cell which is `CategoryCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question "Can we downcast to UItableview to UItableviewcell?" is NO. In the `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` you are actually casting `UITableViewCell` to `CategoryCell` as parent class for all the table cells are `UITableViewCell` and the function `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` on `UITableView` always returns `UITableViewCell` type objects.